# MacBook Pro 2017 - USB C Dock not working / wifi only 2.4GHz

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, lenovo, macbook

ive got a MacBook Pro 14.1 and installed Ubuntu Unity on that mac because i doesn't like mac OS.
According to a guide on github, ive successfully got sound working.
I am using a USB-C Docking station from Lenovo. I think its gen2.
The main problem is the wifi and USB-C Docking station.
the docking station is sometimes working, partial the displays arent working, partial the network port is missing on the system.
After a reboot everythig is working.
On my old lenovo thinkpad, everything is working well.

The second thing is wifi.
Ive got a model with BCM4350 chip.
Out of the box the system was using the generic driver and the wifi was working on 2.4gh, but only on that.
I've tried to install the driver bcmwl-kernel-source , after that the wifi wasn't working.
Any idea whats wrong ?
I know that is a mac book.

Comment: I am not a Mac user, but I have access to a MacBook Air 8.2 for testing purposes. The internal wifi chip, keyboard and trackpad fail to work with Lubuntu. But I had good luck when I bought a USB-C adapter with wired internet (an ethernet port). USB keyboard and mouse work well and I can run Lubuntu from an external SSD connected via USB 3. - I think we can expect a bumpy road getting hardware (including docking stations and adapters) to work with Ubuntu in Mac computers.